# Regular expression in python 2.7.11

Tags: python, regex

I am not sure why the regex - `\b((\+65[\s\-]*)?[3689]\d{3}[\s\-]*\d{4})\b` doesn't work for `+6565066859`

Comment: There is no word boundary between `+` and the start of a string

Comment: @SebastianProske I didn't get you. Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Your regex pattern starts with a word boundary (`\b`) which will match between a word and a non-word-character or start of the string or end of the string. However `+` is not a word character, so it can't match between the start and the `+`.

Comment: Now the `+65` part is optional, so could be omitted, however there is also no place for a word boundary between `+65` and `65` so it can't match there either. And as your phone number pattern requires a fixed with, there it can't match after the `+` either, as the remaining number will be too long.

Comment: oh alright @SebastianProske Thank you. could you suggest a regex to match the above number?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern currently doesn't work because of the word boundary that is placed at the start. Note that a word boundary will match between a word-character and

- a non-word-character
- the start of a string
- the end of a string

In your case `\b` is placed between the start of the string and the `+`, where it will match, thus your first optional group will never match. The rest of the pattern consists of a 8-digit-number (if we forget spaces and hyphens for a moment), but the number you try to test consists of 10 characters, so both word boundaries can't match at the same time.

I think you can rewrite your pattern as `((?:(\+65[\s\-]*)|\b)[3689]\d{3}[\s\-]*\d{4})\b` thus either matching +65 or the word boundary. Not sure if you use the capturing groups in your pattern, so I kept them as they are.